# Дано число А и натуральное число N. Найти результат следующего выражения 1*А + А*2 + А*3 + … + А*N

Tags: ruby

Дано число А и натуральное число N. Найти результат следующего выражения 1*А + А*2 + А*3 + … + А*N.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Курите "Сумма арифметической прогрессии".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A * (n + 1) * n / 2
```

> Привет от маленького Гаусса.

Comment: Ну зачем все это стимулировать??? Так никогда мы не поборим такие мега-вопросы

Comment: @VladSpirin Тут у каждого своя правда. Я видел как Igor помогает и как он же не помогает, я тоже кому-то ситуативно помогаю, а кому-то нет. Это индивидуально всё и ситуативно.

Comment: @AK это я вижу...

Comment: @Igor а какой смысл вообще на такие вопросы отвечать?

Comment: @Vlad Spirin [Так никогда мы не поборим такие мега-вопросы] А Вы такие мега-вопросы никогда не поборете.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я это понимаю, но пытаться все равно стоит, иначе зачем это все...

Comment: @Vlad Spirin Ну не знаю. У меня как раз другой подход, более либеральный.  Не надо бороться с вопросами. Пусть народ спрашивает и пусть студенты просят за них решить учебные задания. Если кто-то захочет, то он решит. Если никто не захочет, вопрос останется без ответа. Хуже от вопроса никому не будет. А студенту разобрать чужое решение своей задачи тоже полезно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, увы, те кто задают такие вопросы, не разбирают свои ответы, мне кажется